# camera intent and priority queue in Android

Tags: android, priority-queue, android-camera-intent

I am currently writing an Android app (API level 2.3.3) that involves taking the 300 highest grayscale values from a photo taken via camera intent.  Following, functions (mainly maths and some calendar/clock based) are performed on the resultant value. I am using Eclipse/emulated camera.

The camera will activate and the photo is taken without a problem, it is when I try to save the photo (and when the pixel sorting and mathematical/calendar functions are to occur), the app crashes.

I tested the app with just the camera intent and a 'dummy' value for the main variable (Y), and this worked fine.

What is going wrong?

Below is the relevant section of code:

```
int[] pixels;   


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "sunpic.jpg";
            File file = new File(_path);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case (1): {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri outputFileUri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap bmp = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), outputFileUri);
                        bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());

                        for(int x = 0; x < bmp.getWidth(); ++x) {
                            for(int y = 0; y < bmp.getHeight(); ++y) {
                                int index = y * bmp.getWidth() + x;
                                int R = (pixels[index] >> 16) & 0xff;
                                int G = (pixels[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                                int B = pixels[index] & 0xff;
                                Double Grey = (0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B); 

                                int topSize = 300;
                                // priority queue to save the largest topSize values
                                PriorityQueue<Double> pq;
                                pq = new PriorityQueue<Double>(topSize+1);

                                double nv = Grey.floatValue();
                                if (pq.size() < topSize || pq.peek() < nv) {
                                    // remove the smallest value from the queue only if it is full
                                    if (pq.size() == topSize) {
                                        pq.poll();
                                    }
                                    pq.add(nv);
                                } 
                                double sum = 0;
                                for(Double d : pq) {
                                    sum += d;

                                }
                                double Y = sum / 300;
```

In the XML Manifest, I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

LogCat errors/warnings:

```
06-09 02:10:40.076: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-09 02:10:41.646: E/Trace(4464): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-09 02:10:49.907: W/ActivityManager(289): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-09 02:10:50.817: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-09 02:10:51.106: W/ActivityManager(289): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40ec7900 inActivity}
06-09 02:10:55.547: W/ActivityManager(289): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-09 02:10:55.587: W/EGL_emulation(4464): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-09 02:10:56.477: W/ActivityManager(289): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfe978 that was originally bound here
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfe978 that was originally bound here
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-09 02:10:56.487: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707): null
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cfe978 that was originally bound here
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-09 02:10:56.510: E/StrictMode(707):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-09 02:10:56.557: W/ActivityManager(289): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40e69780
06-09 02:11:02.557: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4464): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
06-09 02:11:03.158: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-09 02:11:14.797: E/WVMExtractor(40): Failed to open libwvm.so
06-09 02:11:15.637: E/WVMExtractor(40): Failed to open libwvm.so
06-09 02:11:22.179: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-09 02:11:23.076: W/EGL_emulation(1762): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-09 02:11:23.256: W/ActivityManager(289): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-09 02:11:23.716: W/ActivityManager(289): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40fb5d68 u0 com.android.camera/.Camera}
06-09 02:11:24.146: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-09 02:11:24.166: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-09 02:11:29.237: W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(378): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
06-09 02:11:34.387: W/AudioTrack(40): releaseBuffer() track 0x2a02af18 name=0x1 disabled, restarting
06-09 02:11:36.000: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4464): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
06-09 02:11:36.087: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(4464): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-09 02:11:38.667: W/ActivityManager(289): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40fb5d68 u0 com.android.camera/.Camera}
06-09 02:11:38.950: W/AudioFlinger(40): session id 9 not found for pid 40
06-09 02:11:39.047: W/dalvikvm(4464): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-09 02:11:39.057: W/AudioFlinger(40): session id 10 not found for pid 40
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth/irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3319)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:73)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
06-09 02:11:39.377: E/AndroidRuntime(4464):     ... 11 more
06-09 02:11:39.897: W/ActivityManager(289):   Force finishing activity irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth/.MainActivity
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.Surface.<init>(Surface.java:289)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>(SurfaceView.java:96)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.camera.Camera.onCreate(Camera.java:1131)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-09 02:11:40.199: E/StrictMode(1762):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'release' not called
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.Surface.<init>(Surface.java:289)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.SurfaceView.<init>(SurfaceView.java:97)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:643)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.camera.Camera.onCreate(Camera.java:1131)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-09 02:11:40.647: E/StrictMode(1762):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 02:11:42.377: W/ActivityManager(289): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40ec7900 u0 irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth/.MainActivity}
06-09 02:11:43.637: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-09 02:11:47.517: W/ActivityManager(289): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-09 02:11:48.175: W/ActivityManager(289): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-09 02:11:48.647: W/InputDispatcher(289): channel '40fc3848 irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth/irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
06-09 02:11:48.647: E/InputDispatcher(289): channel '40fc3848 irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth/irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-09 02:11:48.767: W/InputDispatcher(289): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '40fc3848 irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth/irradiance.aerosolopticaldepth.MainActivity (server)'
06-09 02:11:49.668: W/ActivityManager(289): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0b180 that was originally bound here
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0b180 that was originally bound here
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-09 02:11:50.137: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-09 02:11:50.387: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707): null
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0b180 that was originally bound here
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-09 02:11:50.650: E/StrictMode(707):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-09 02:11:50.677: W/ActivityManager(289): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41150178
06-09 02:11:50.927: W/EGL_emulation(407): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0a990 that was originally bound here
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d0a990 that was originally bound here
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-09 02:11:51.347: E/ActivityThread(707):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-09 02:11:52.498: W/ActivityManager(289): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{40f7a298 u0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher}
```

Comment: What is the LogCat output?

Comment: Edited in the logcat warnings/errors - all I could fit into this post

Comment: NullPointerException at line 73 of MainActivity.java. Which line is it?

Comment: it's the one that states:

case (1): {

Comment: Really? That's not a place for a NullPointerException. It must be happening in some other line. Have you changed the code since you posted it?

Comment: nope, the code is still the same as posted. I am thinking that the error is occurring after that line.

Comment: I think so too. My candidates are lines 75, 78 and 79. Add some checks for null (they can perform Log.i() for instance) and verify the log output again.

Comment: Oh wait a sec... line 73 is actually:

Uri outputFileUri = data.getData();

Comment: Well, that's it then. onActivityResult() is receveing a null intent. You should be able to go ahead from there.

Comment: I just came to that same conclusion - now to find out what is going on.

Comment: These might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890757/android-camera-data-intent-returns-null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627900/camera-intent-data-null-in-onactivityresultint-requestcode-int-resultcode-int http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672806/camera-intent-returns-null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248327/my-android-camera-uri-is-returning-a-null-value-but-the-samsung-fix-is-in-place

Comment: I don't know what's going on... I even did the 1st option of the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042695/how-to-get-camera-result-as-a-uri-in-data-folder/10229228#10229228 and still are getting the same errors

Comment: Well, I am completely lost - the LogCat is still giving Nullpointer errors from the same place and the camera just hangs once the picture is taken. I seriously am lost and would appreciate some concrete advice on the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still are having no luck at all, I have changed the camera intent code to:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "sunpic.jpg";
            File file = new File(_path);
            //Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);             
            //File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);


            }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    //Uri file = data.getData();
                    FileInputStream is;
                    try {
                        is = new FileInputStream("mnt/sdcard/sunpic.jpg");


                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    //Bitmap bmp = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), file);
                    //Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                    bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, bmp.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
```

The rest of this is identical to what is in my original post.

The logcat is empty and as soon as I take a picture on the camera, it freezes.

What I tried earlier did not include

```
FileInputStream is;
                    try {
                        is = new FileInputStream("mnt/sdcard/sunpic.jpg");
```

and had the next line as

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream("sunpic.jpg");
```

But that consistently spat out NullPointer errors, to which I really do not understand why, despite reading many other threads/other web resources about it.

Comment: No offence but I think you need to read a basic Java and basic Android book before posting here...